# To What Extent Should The Language of a Question Be Modified

Tags: discussion

I came across this question [ios click back button pass value can't find selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129679/ios-click-back-button-pass-value-cant-find-selector) and was wondering to what extent it is appropriate to correct the language of the question. It is obviously posted by someone who's writing is not the best, but is it appropriate to correct the mistakes (I will assume that this person is not a native English speaker – my apologies if I am mistaken). I have seen/made edits about grammar in the past and I think that they help to make a question more readable so that others will be better able to understand. Here the issue is that I would be changing/rearranging entire sentences and I run the risk of making an edit which is a. not what the user and/or b. not going to be understood by the OP.

For instance lets look at the sentence:

> But I need click the back button on the navigation bar , it will pass a value return to A uiviewcontroller.

This sentence could be changed to: "But I need to pass a return value to `AViewController` when the back button on the navigation bar is clicked". This could help future readers of the question, but I also feel that such an edit is a fairly large change and might actually not be what the OP intended.

I could ask the OP to rephrase some of the sentences, but I'm not sure if that will help as their knowledge of English would limit them when trying to come up with a different manner to rephrase the question.

In summary: How should this sort of situation be handled and what is the appropriate amount of editing for questions written in confusing English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can reword a question without changing its core meaning, go for it.
The OP can always re-edit the question or rollback the edit if you misjudge their meaning.

If the question is so unclear that you need clarification before you feel comfortable editing, you can ask the OP with a comment.

Usually users who don't communicate well in English will appreciate a good edit. In the long run you're helping them get a good answer, don't be afraid to lend a hand.